# can someone give me an example on how collaboration is difficult without the Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

i understand the technology and i understand how it helps in two domains which are voting and currency but i don't understand how the Blockchain helps in other domains such as health care or supplychain, i mean what is wrong with today's health care and supplychain !

Comment: It doesn't help "voting" and indeed also not in health care or supply chain. Whatever kind of "hash chain" those domains may possibly use at some point is more likely to be similar to what git or bittorrent does (and has done for longer than bitcoin exists).

Comment: Regarding voting and blockchain systems, this is a great article: https://benlog.com/2017/12/28/blockchain-and-voting/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Nobody can give such an example.

Simple reason: Collaboration existed long before blockchain was invented.

Satoshi Nakamoto started chapter 12. Conclusion of his paper with the sentence:

> We have proposed a system for electronic transactions without relying on trust.

If you take a deeper look into the technology you realize trust got in fact replaced by distributed computing power. Causing another problem. Namely, how to distribute this computing power in a trustworthy way.

Since voting (as we usually do in democracies) and health care heavily rely on trust in the persons involved I find it difficult to see any reason why and how a blockchain could help in these fields.

[Satoshi Nakamoto's paper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf)